# Numbers in UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using the following code

```
String str="12345";
byte[] b=str.getBytes("UTF-8");

String str1=new String(b,"UTF-8");
System.out.println(str1);
```

I am getting the following result

```
 =♠4??o;◄EZZ▬▲]
```

Why is it not giving the original string?

Comment: That's not the output that I get from that code. It actually works just fine (and I see no reason why this should output anything other than `12345`).

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your output. I have also tested your code and it prints '12345' correctly.

Comment: Works for me. Try adding this line and telling us what it says. System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to `System.out.println("12345")`. If result is the same, that means that you system encoding is not suitable. In this case(if you use cmd) try `chcp 65001` and retry. Another option is to try to set system property file.encoding=UTF-8 before running ide.

Comment: If the results are **not** the same as the result of the code in the question, then something is seriously wrong with his Java installation.